# Embedded images (inline) within html body in email showing as attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have successfully added a image(logo) as inline in html e-mail message.
However it also showing link to download such images as attachment. In yahoo mail all the images available in attachment

My stuff as follows,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="cid:mylogo.png" />
        <table>
            .
            .
            .
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
 MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
 DataSource ds = new FileDataSource("D:/temp/mylogo.png");
 imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
 imagePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<mylogo.png>");
 imagePart.setDisposition(Part.INLINE);
 multipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);
```

when i open a generated mail in email clients like yahoo and gmail the image is showing as what i expect but it also showing as a attachment. how do i disable downloading such image?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this, the image is sent as an attachment so it is shown as an attachment. You can't prevent this since you don't have any control on the mail client.

Instead, upload your image somewhere on the web and change your `src` to its URL. (example: `<img src="http://example.com/mylogo.png" />`).

Comment: Other than URL is any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal on Mobile Mail Clients, they do that so people can download the mail embed images on the phone. If you open it on a computer the image will not be displayed as an attachment.